# Calculate the amount of km traveled by each person in each vehicle

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a rather large amount of odometer values from a vehicle fleet of about 40 vehicles,
driven by different persons, but in my example below, I am keeping it simple.

I have everything imported into pandas, and next to my odometer values, I have who was driving the vehicle when the odometer log event was triggered (usually they would trigger every km, but sometimes it triggers more, sometimes it triggers less)

now I need to figure out the amount of km vehicle X have traveled, while person Y was behind the wheel, but I am not sure how.

```
matrix = [(1, '501', "Me"),
         (1, '502', "Me"),
         (1, '502', "Wife"),
         (1, '503', "Wife"),
         (1, '504', "Wife"),
         (1, '505', "Wife"),
         (1, '506', "Wife"),
         (1, '507', "Wife"),
         (1, '508', "Wife"),
         (1, '509', "Me"),
         (1, '510', "Me"),
         (1, '511', "Me"),
         (1, '512', "Me"),
         (1, '520', "Wife"),
         (1, '522', "Me"),
         (1, '523', "Me"),
         (1, '524', "Me"),
         (1, '524', "Me"),
         (1, '524', "Me"),
         (1, '524', "Me"),
         (1, '525', "Me"),
         (2, '126', "Me"),
         (2, '127', "Me"),
         (2, '128', "Me"),
         (2, '129', "Me"),
         ]

# Create a DataFrame object
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=['Vehicle', 'ODOmeter', 'Who'])

print (dfObj)

print ("\nVehicle 1 have driven 10 km with Me behind the wheel\nand 14 km with Wife behind the wheel\nVehicle 2 have driven 3 km with me behind the wheel")
```

Comment: Are you possibly going to get something like `[(1, '501', 'Me'), (1, '600', 'Me')]` eg - you need to consider the value of the gap, or things like: `[(1, '100', 'Me'), (1, '105', 'Wife'), (1, '110', 'Me'), (1, '112', 'Wife')]` and what'd happen there if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy and Paste answer

Here a function to calculate and print the desired output:

```
def print_kilometers(dfObj):
    dfObj['ODOmeter'] = dfObj['ODOmeter'].astype(float)
    dfObj["diff"]= dfObj.groupby("Vehicle")["ODOmeter"].diff()
    sum_km = dfObj.groupby(["Who", "Vehicle"])["diff"].sum()

    for i, v in sum_km.items():
       print("Vehicle {} have driven {} km with {} behind the wheel".format(i[1], v, i[0]))
```

### Explanation

If I understand well you problem you can simply calculate the diffirence between the km of a vehicle and use a the `groupby` function provided by `pandas`. Using your dataframe as example you can do something like:

```
dfObj['ODOmeter'] = dfObj['ODOmeter'].astype(float)
dfObj["diff"]= dfObj.groupby("Vehicle")["ODOmeter"].diff()
sum_km = dfObj.groupby(["Who", "Vehicle"])["diff"].sum()
```

In the first line I convert the `ODOmeter` column to float, (if kilometers can only be integer values you can switch to int), in the second I added a column to dataframe with the diff and in the last line I group by `Who` and `Vehicle` and summed over `diff` columns.
You can loop and print the results:

```
for i, v in sum_km.items():
    print("Vehicle {} have driven {} km with {} behind the wheel".format(i[1], v, i[0]))
```

Comment: Ahh, so diff don't just take the difference between first and last, but from each datapoint.
This solved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to cast the Odometer to the proper type:

```
dfObj['ODOmeter'] = dfObj['ODOmeter'].astype(int)
```

Then you calculate the difference between two Odometer datapoints for each vehicle, giving you the tripmeter

```
dfObj['Tripmeter'] = dfObj.groupby('Vehicle')['ODOmeter'].diff()
```

And then simply add up the Tripmeters for each Vehicle and Person

```
dfObj.groupby(['Vehicle', 'Who'])["Tripmeter"].sum()
# Vehicle  Who 
# 1        Me      10.0
#          Wife    14.0
# 2        Me       3.0
# Name: ODOmeter, dtype: float64
```